# Perl Locale Warning when using VSCODE

Tags: perl, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run Perl in VSCODE and am getting this error (on Windows):

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        (possibly more locale environment variables)
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the system default locale ("English_United States.1252").
```

I am not sure how to update my locale settings... and can only find info online regarding this for Linux/Ubuntu and for MAC OS.

Comment: This `perl`... Are you able to find it and do `perl -v`? I'm looking for something like `This is perl 5, version 38, subversion 0 (v5.38.0) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi` (If you see something like this in the VSCode terminal, that would be perfect. Provide that instead.)

Comment: The reason I ask is because I think you're using a Perl built for a unix emulation environment (e.g. MSYS2, MSYS, Cygwin) instead of a native build (e.g. Strawberry Perl). The solution would be specific to that environment. Windows builds of Perl don't care about unix locale vars.

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue.

PS C:\Users\jacob\OneDrive\ZZZ> perl -v
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:

This is perl 5, version 38, subversion 2 (v5.38.2) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

Copyright 1987-2023, Larry Wall

...

PS C:\Users\jacob\OneDrive\ZZZ> (Get-Command perl).Path
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue with VS Code's integrated terminal, using PowerShell. I did not have this problem using Windows Terminal for PowerShell. All this using Strawberry Perl.

The solution I found is to turn `terminal.integrated.detectLocale` to `off` in Settings. I just found it, and I don't know if there are other effects, but that switch gets rid of that warning.